# Activate plugin on fresh wordpress installation always forcing https on localhost

Tags: wordpress, mamp

Every time I try to activate a plugin in a fresh localhost WordPress installation, the link is forced to use `https`. No other links in the fresh install are doing this.  I have checked the SITE_URL and database settings and none included `https`.

I have reinstalled MAMP and have no other plugins installed.  It's a fresh base installation of WordPress.  I'm using Mac OS El Capitain.

I also checked and all the links to the activate plugin buttons in the source code are `http://localhost/`.

What else could be causing this?  How can I find the culprit?

Comment: It may be something related to your local server configuration. Only happens on a fresh wordpress install? Does it happens on a normal php install?

Comment: I worked around by installing self-signed SSL certificates for MAMP. https://gist.github.com/jfloff/5138826

Comment: I suspect it may be a WordPress plugin to `Force HTTPS` that I installed, which may alter Apache's mod_rewrite module.  Attempts to uninstall and reinstall MAMP possibly did not clear some of the settings.